# How to filter out the part before the equal sign in a shell variable with regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, nano

I have been trying to find a working regex to filter out only variables in a shell script but not been able to. I am not talking about the the actual variable but the string that creates it. As an example I have been trying to `egrep` the variables out of this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

flavor=${1:-dzen2}

function gmail() {
while true
do
    inbox_count=$(wget -q -O- --auth-no-challenge --user=something@gmail.com --password=something 'https://mail.goog$
    echo "Gg:$inbox_count"
    sleep 60
done
}

function weather() {
while true
do
    weather_stat=$($HOME/.config/i3/./weather.sh)
    echo "F$weather_stat"
    sleep 900
done
}

function time_date() {
while true
do
    klocka=$(date +'%A den %d %B v%V  %H:%M')
    echo "S$klocka"
    sleep 10
done < <(echo)
}

bspc control --put-status
xtitle -sf "T%s" > "$PANEL_FIFO" &
weather > "$PANEL_FIFO" &
gmail > "$PANEL_FIFO" &
time_date > "$PANEL_FIFO" &
case "$flavor" in
bar)
    cat "$PANEL_FIFO" | .config/bspwm/panel_bar | bar
;;
dzen2)
    . .config/bspwm/panel_colors
    PANEL_HEIGHT=14
    FONT_FAMILY='Dejavu Sans'
    FONT_SIZE=9
    cat "$PANEL_FIFO" | .config/bspwm/panel_dzen2 -f "$FONT_FAMILY" -s "$FONT_SIZE" | \
    dzen2 -h $PANEL_HEIGHT -dock -ta l -title-name panel -fn "${FONT_FAMILY}:pixelsize=${FONT_SIZE}" \
    -fg "$COLOR_FOREGROUND" -bg "$COLOR_BACKGROUND"
;;
esac
```

I need this for my Nano colouring theme. So far I have been using  `"^[A-Za-z0-9 ].*="` which get some but not all of the variables. And if I do something like `"[A-Za-z0-9 ].*="` it takes to much. I think it might be that those other variables like `klocka=` start with tabulation.. but haven't been able to successfully solve it.

I want it to filter out the variable before the equal sign. Like this `FONT_SIZE=` so I can theme that part in Nano. I need the regex and not a sed or awk as that is the syntax in Nano.

Comment: Try `"^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]*="`

Comment: There can be some or no white space before a declaration so `^\s*+\w[\w\d]*+(?==)` ought to work.

Comment: Actually `^s*[A-Za-z0-9_]*=` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a simple regex like this seems to work for me:

```
^\s*(\w*)=
```

It captures the variable name. Note that as soon as you have scripts which define multiple variables on the same line, this won't work.

Example: http://www.regex101.com/r/sE8zN8

Comment: Damnit! Did one almost exactly as this but without the ()... but yours work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^\s*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*=
```

This allows for arbitrary whitespace at the beginning of the line, followed by a valid identifier (letter or underscore followed by any number of letters, numbers, and underscores), followed *immediately* by an equal sign.

This will still let through certain command invocations that prefix a command with a temporary environment modification, but block those is beyond the scope of an easily written regular expression:

```
FOO=3 BAR=5 myCommand arg1 arg2
```

Comment: I don't know why but when I try to egrep the file with this one.. it does not work. I have tried similar regex's without luck. If i remove the ```^``` it finds the last part of all the variables.. like ```ZE=``` but not the full word.

Comment: I forgot the `*` after the second `[...]` group, so the above would only match exactly-2-letter parameter names before.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use `\w` instead of the second character class? They are virtually the same thing.

Comment: @mart1n Mostly because I forgot about it, but also it does not include the underscore character.

Comment: @chepner `\w` does include the underscore: '\w stands for "word character", usually [A-Za-z0-9_]. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits.' -- http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Ah, the man page for `egrep` has a small error then. It incorrectly defines `\w` as a synonym for `[[:alnum:]]`, which does not include the underscore.

Comment: @chepner The `egrep` man page I'm looking at (GNU grep 2.14) states: "The symbol \w is a synonym for [_[:alnum:]]". So it does include alphanumeric characters plus an underscore.

Comment: @mart1n Good to know. I was looking at GNU grep 2.6.3, (which works, despite the man page being in error).